# How to auto populate new column based on another column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to auto-populate a column based on another column's choice.

For Example, Column A (labeled Job Title) there are 4 choices. I would like to have another column (Column B) auto populate with text based on a lookup from another list.

I have tried several ways to do this and have come up empty. My current method seems to have gotten me closer than the previous ways.

I have created a column (Column B) labeled Default Job Access. That column is a calculated column and in the formula, I have `=IF([Job Title] = CSP;"TRUE";"FALSE")`.

If I can get this to work, then I will change TRUE and FALSE to text stating the job access. If this doesn't make sense, I apologize. I am just frustrated.

Comment: What is "CSP"? A text value? If so, it needs quotes. Calculated columns cannot directly reference a Lookup column. There's a workaround using a SharePoint Designer workflow that copies the value from the Lookup column into a Single Line of Text column. Let me know if you are interested in that.

Comment: When adding a Lookup column to a list, you can select multiple columns to display. So if your list with the lookup data has a key column with the Job Title, the lookup column can also add columns for display from the lookup date such as JobCode, Hourly Rate, etc. Select a Job Title and three columns are then updated.

Comment: In this case, CSP is an option on a choice menu. Im not too familiar with SharePoint Designer workflows, but do have access to Designer and willing to learn =)  Ill give your 2nd option a try and see what happens.

Comment: I added a calculated column, but the results only show up on the next screen. Im hoping to make it that once a selection is made from the choice, it will populate a new column within the same list. The more i think about it, the more i believe it came happen due to lists being static.

Comment: I think these articles would be helpful **[Auto Populate Field Values based on Lookup Selection In SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/autofill-list-form-fields-based-on-lookup-selection-in-sharepoint/)** or this **[SharePoint Auto Populate Column based on another Column](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/auto-populate-column-based-on-another-column/)**

Answer (score 0):

To auto populate new column based on another column, you can create two Level cascading drop down in SharePoint 2013.

Here are some articles fro your reference.

InfoPath 2013 Web Browser- Creating Cascading Dropdown Fields with no Code:

http://msreddysharepoint.blogspot.sg/2012/12/infopath-2013-web-browser-creating.html

Create two Level cascading drop down in SharePoint 2013 using SPServices:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using